# How to know which are required and recommended linked data properties to use from schema.org

Tags: linked-data, ontology, semantic-web

On this page, https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#completeness we can read:

> - Specify all **required** properties for your rich result type. Items that
>   are missing required properties are not eligible for rich results.
> - The more **recommended** properties that you provide, the higher quality
>   the result is to users. (...)

But on [schema.org](https://schema.org/), I'm not able to find which are the *required* and which are the *recommended* properties.

Are these *required* and *recommended* properties only a thing which is understandable for the google search algorithms to work well, or are they *intrinsic* values of any properties of the [schema.org](https://schema.org/) vocabulary? In the latter case, how and where can I find them (I'm not able to figure it out on [schema.org](https://schema.org/))?

Answer (score 1):

> Are these required and recommended properties only a thing which is understandable for the Google search algorithms to work well?

Yes. Follow additional guidelines in the documentation for your specific type. E.g., for [Movie](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/movie#movie): required properties are `name` and `image`.

See also https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1715.